# Vulnerabilities with open file

Tags: perl

I am using the following code to open a file and write in it.

```
my $WlmScriptReportFile = "WlmScriptReport.out";
open (my $fh, '>',$WlmScriptReportFile) or die "Could not open report file $WlmScriptReportFile";
```

But this is detected as vulnerable(PrivilegeEscalation) as per the scanning tool I am using. I read some posts about this but this looks valid to me. Any pointer what is wrong in this?

Comment: What is that "_scanning tool_"? What does its "_vulnerable_" mean?  The one thing that _is_ missing is to check whether the `open` call succeeded, commonly `open ...  or die "Can't open $file: $!";`

Comment: I am using HCL appscan to scan my code and this is detected as a malicious/vulnerable code. The command succeeds and the file is getting written as expected.

Comment: My best guess is that this is an outdated check based on two-argument open which absolutely could lead to privilege escalation since input can cause it to run arbitrary processes rather than just open files. Calling open with a third argument makes this impossible, though there are still the concerns @ikegami mentions.

Comment: Ah, that "_PrivilegeEscalation_" is it -- writing to (changing) the file system is apparently an escalation of whatever the tool considers OK.  Can the tool be configured?  Is there anything unusual about permissions, on the file / partition / filesystem, for the group/user ... ?

Comment: Note for the edit: the one thing you absolutely need to have in that `die` is the [`$!` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables), which tells you what the error actually is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That command can be used to replace or clobber any file to which the process's user has sufficient access, or to create a file in any directory to which the process's user has sufficient access. This has all kinds of ramifications.

If the value of `$WlmScriptReportFile` is constructed in part or in whole from values outside of the control of the user as which program is running (potentially including the Current Work Directory), then the command could potentially be used maliciously.

Comment: Updated the question. The variable is constructed in the same script. This is a single perl file and the type of vulnerability is PrivilegeEscalation so I think you are right. But I am not sure how to avoid that.

Comment: hmm I tried changing to `open(my $fh, '>', \"/tmp/test.txt") or die "Could not open report file"` with fully qualified path of the file but still same error.

Comment: I think it is not smart. `open(my $fh, '>', "/test.txt")` did not work as well !!

Comment: I was using a variable initially. That did not work either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204626/discussion-between-codec-and-ikegami).